# Direct sum of vector spaces and dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $U$ is a finite dimensional vector space and $U=U_1\oplus ... \oplus U_n$. Then $\dim{(U)} = \dim{(U_1)} + ... + \dim{(U_n)}.$

---

I have looked at the duplicates but the answers don't really make sense so I must post myself.

---

Since $U=U_1\oplus ... \oplus \,U_n$, every $u\in U$ may be expressed uniquely as a sum $u = u_1 + ... + u_n$, with $u_i\in U_i$, for $i=1,...,n$. Suppose $\{u_1, ..., u_n\}$ is a basis of $U$, so that $\dim{(U)} = n$.

Now I want to show $\dim{(U_1)} + ... + \dim{(U_n)} = n$. I want to find a basis of each $U_i$ then find the size of those bases. But I'm not really sure how to find the bases. Can someone provide some hints?

Comment: Could you explain what you are having trouble with in the duplicates?

Comment: Be careful you have used "$n$" in two different ways, you should change one of them to $m$.

Comment: In other words you will only be able to find a basis $\{u_1,\dots,u_n\}$ of $U$ if all $U_i$ are one-dimensional.

Comment: Hint: You may say that $\dim {U_k}=m_k$ for each $k=1,2\ldots,n$ and pick a basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_{m_k}\}$ of $U_k$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go the other way: Pick bases $\{u^{(i)}_j\}_{j=1}^{\dim U_i}$ of $U_i$. By assumption, any $u\in U$ can be uniquely written as $u=\sum_{i=1}^n u_i$ where $u_i\in U_i$.
Now using the bases each $u_i$ can be uniquely written as
$$u_i = \sum_{j=1}^{\dim U_i} \alpha_j^{(i)} u^{(i)}_j$$
And thus $u$ can be uniquely written as
$$u = \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^{\dim U_i} \alpha_j^{(i)} u_j^{(i)} = \sum_{l=1}^{\sum_{i=1}^n \dim U_i} \beta_l u_l$$
Where $\{u_l\}_{l=1}^{\sum_{i=1}^n \dim U_i}$ is a concatenation of all the bases of the $U_i$s and $\beta_l$ are the concatenation of all the corresponding $\alpha_j^{(i)}$s.
This proves that $\{u_l\}_{l=1}^{\sum_{i=1}^n \dim U_i}$ is a basis of $U$ and therefor
$$\dim U = \sum_{i=1}^n \dim U_i$$